# Read from properties file stored in system in agularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Could  anyone tell me how to  read properties  file   in Angularjs. Property file  could be  any where in system. I want something  like ,  reading java  file  by specifying  path.
Thanks  in advance

Comment: Maybe you can use a file select box together with fileReader (HTML5) to retrieve the content of file immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways. one is reading properties file in angularJs

```
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('connection.properties').then(function (response) {
    console.log('a is ', response.data.a);
    console.log('b is ', response.data.b);
  });
});
```

another is reading properties file in spring

```
  <bean id="messageSource"
  class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"    autowire="byName"> 
<property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" /> 
<property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" /> 
 <property name="cacheSeconds" value="1"/>
</bean>
```